# API trying to use code on the same server - require path issue

Tags: php

**Goal**: to require files from an old monolithic code base that is still an active website, and use those files as logic for an API running on the same server in its own instance of PHP. Hoping to leverage the old codes deeply buried business logic. As the old code base must run as we transition it away.

**Problem**: The old code base uses $_SERVER[‘DOCUMENT_ROOT’] in its require paths. So the new API can’t include those files because it thinks that the document root is the root of its own web root. The old code files contain MANY requires, and those required pages include many requires, so going through and replacing the document root var with relative paths would be a mammoth job. For every new route I write I need to go through all of the old code requires and changes the paths to relative.

Using curl from the new API works fine, but I’m trying to avoid the overhead.

I thought of using an $_ENV var but again it’s the server environment and it has the same problem.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Why not overwrite `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` before you require the old files, and restore it after?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest by far would be to write a script that automatically updates all the require paths. This is probably far better than any workaround you can come up with.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as a comment?

Comment: @Adam given the question, I feel that this is the most optimal solution. It would certainly solve OP's problem. Do you feel that there's something missing from my answer?